# After I rebase and then sync, history doubles in the PR and shows unrelated changes

Tags: git, github, rebase

I've asked this question poorly earlier today, now that I tried a few more things I may have a better understanding.

Situation:

- I've a fork of F#
- I've a local `master` and a local `workbranch` and both are also in my fork.
- There a PR of the workbranch
- Workbranch has 7 files changed
- A PR was merged into upstream master that is useful to my own work, so I want to rebase my branch
- My workbranch is 1 commit behind master. I want that last commit, which has 26 changed files
- I like to see my changes as-if after the head of master (hence: rebase)

The commands I did:

```
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git push origin/master

git checkout workbranch // up-to-date with origin
git rebase master
git rebase --continue   // after solving merge conflict
git pull .    // not sure why there were changes to be pulled, was this where I went wrong?
git push .
```

After this, the result was that I see:

- 21 commits of earlier today
- 1 commit from master with those 26 changed files
- another 8 commits that are exactly equal to some of the earlier 21 commits
- a merge commit of this rebase
- the diff shows 33 files changed

In the branch-comparison overview on github.com, in my fork, I see:

- 21 commits of earlier today
- another 8 commits like above
- the merge commit of the rebase
- the diff here shows 7 files changed

What I expected to see is **my original commits, each only once, not duplicated, the merge-commit, and there should be no commit from master**.

I suspect it has something to do with the pull-before-push.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normal.  Not *desirable*, mind you, but normal—it's one reason some people avoid using `git rebase` entirely.

## Long: Why this happens

Remember first what a Git commit is and does:

- Each commit stores a snapshot of all of your files, plus some metadata: the name and email address of the person who made the commit, date-and-time stamps, and so on.
- Each commit has a unique number.  This number isn't a simple count—it doesn't go 1, 2, 3, etc—and is instead a big, ugly, random-looking (but not random at all) *hash ID*.  The hash ID is how two Gits can tell whether they both have a commit, because this hash ID is computed the same way in *every* Git.  If their Git has a commit and you don't, your Git doesn't have the commit number in its database.  If your Git has a commit and they don't, your Git has the commit number (and the commit) in its database, and they don't.

Moreover, *history* in a Git repository is simply the set of commits.  Git makes this work out by storing, in each commit, the commit number—the hash ID—of the commit's *parent* commit, or, for a merge commit, parent commits (plural).  These are the commits that come *before* this commit.

If we disregard merge commits, we get simple, backwards-looking chains of commits, that we can draw like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the actual hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  In `H`'s metadata, Git has stored the actual hash ID of commit `G`.  So by reading the contents of `H`, Git can find the commit number for `G`, which lets Git read commit `G`, which contains the commit number for `F`, and so on.

A *branch name* in Git simply holds the commit number—the big ugly hash ID—of the *last* commit in the chain.  So if your branch `master` has the above commits, we can draw that like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

We don't really need the backwards-pointing arrows *between* commits, as long as we remember that they always point backwards, because nothing inside any commit can ever be changed.  That includes the hash ID of the parent commit.

Branch names, and other names like remote-tracking names, however, *move*.  So we'll draw their arrows to remind us.

#### Drawing your setup

We can draw your initial situation like this:

```
...--F   <-- master, origin/master, upstream/master
      \
       G--H   <-- workbranch, origin/workbranch
```

Now we update our `upstream/master`, where there are some new commits, with their own unique hash IDs:

```
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
```

This gives us:

```
       I--J   <-- upstream/master
      /
...--F   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
      \
       G--H   <-- workbranch, origin/workbranch
```

The `git checkout` step makes sure that our *current* branch is `master`, i.e., that we're working with commit `F`.  That's why we have the special name `HEAD` attached to the branch name `master` here.

Next, we have Git *move* our name `master` to point to the last of the new commits we just got from `upstream`:

```
git merge upstream/master
```

which produces:

```
       I--J   <-- master (HEAD), upstream/master
      /
...--F   <-- origin/master
      \
       G--H   <-- workbranch
```

Note how `master` now points to existing commit `J`.  The Git over at `origin` does not even have commits `I-J` yet, and our memory of its `master`, in our `origin/master`, still points to commit `F`.

Finally, we run:

```
git push origin master    # note: not origin/master
```

This has our Git call up the Git over at `origin`.  That's why this is `origin master` and not `origin/master`: we want to call up the Git at `origin`, and send commits based on *our* `master`, which is also why the last part is `master` and not `origin/master`.  So we send commits `I-J` (which we got from `upstream` via `upstream`'s `master`) to `origin`, and ask `origin` to set *their* `master` to point to commit `J`.

Assuming they obey, this is what we have locally at the end of this process:

```
       I--J   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master, upstream/master
      /
...--F
      \
       G--H   <-- workbranch, origin/workbranch
```

Note that no *commits* have changed during all of this.  This entire process was about getting commits into particular Git repositories (ours, and the one at `origin`) from some other repository (the one at `upstream`), and updating our branch name (`master`) and the name `master` in the Git at `origin` (which our Git keeps a memory of in our `origin/master`).

(This is all quite confusing: it takes a long time to get used to all the repetition.  I find it helps to think of each repository as a different "person": Mr Upstream knows about commits `I-J`, then we learn about them, then we tell Mr Origin.)

#### Rebase pretends to change commits

For `git rebase` to do its job, it has to *pretend* to change a commit.  This is actually quite impossible.  Instead, rebase takes existing commits and uses them to make *new* commits, that are slightly different, and therefore have a different commit number.

Let's re-draw our final situation without the up-kink after commit `F`.  We can draw the graph however we like, as long as we can follow from names to commits and then follow the internal backwards-pointing arrows.  The `git log --graph` command draws a graph with newer commits towards the *top* of the graph, but for StackOverflow, I prefer to draw mine with newer commits towards the right.

```
...--F--I--J   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master, upstream/master
      \
       G--H   <-- workbranch, origin/workbranch
```

What we'd like to do is pretend we make commit `G` from commit `J`.  Of course, we didn't, but `git rebase` can:

- use Git's *detached HEAD* mode to extract commit `J` to the work-tree;
- use `git cherry-pick` to copy commit `G` here;
- use `git cherry-pick` again to copy commit `H`; and finally
- force the name `workbranch` to identify the last-copied commit.

The rebase operation can hit a snag during each of the `git cherry-pick` steps, and it looks like yours did so once.

We start by telling Git to extract commit `H` and attach `HEAD` here.  That's how `git rebase` will decide which commits to copy: it will look at `HEAD`.  So we run:

```
git checkout workbranch
```

which gives us:

```
...--F--I--J   <-- master, origin/master, upstream/master
      \
       G--H   <-- workbranch (HEAD), origin/workbranch
```

Again, no *commits* have changed, but we're now working with the files extracted from commit `H`.

Then we run:

```
git rebase master
```

Git now lists out the raw hash IDs of the commits that are on `workbranch` that are not on `master`.  Note that `master` contains commits `...-F-I-J`, ending at `J`, while `workbranch` contains commits `...-F-G-H`, ending at `H`.  The `F`s and earlier commits get canceled out, and the `I-J` commits aren't on `workbranch` at all, so the list of commits to copy here is just `G` and `H`.

(In your case, there were more than two commits to copy, but the result should be clear enough.)

Next, because we said `git rebase master`, Git does a special detached-HEAD mode checkout of commit `J`:

```
...--F--I--J   <-- HEAD, master, origin/master, upstream/master
      \
       G--H   <-- workbranch, origin/workbranch
```

Now Git uses `git cherry-pick` (or something more or less equivalent, depending on your Git vintage and the flags you pass to `git rebase`) to copy the *changes* made in commit `G`, to where `HEAD` is now.  If all goes well, Git makes the new commit on its own.  To remember that it is a copy of `G`, we'll call this `G'`:

```
             G'  <-- HEAD
            /
...--F--I--J   <-- master, origin/master, upstream/master
      \
       G--H   <-- workbranch, origin/workbranch
```

The rebase command proceeds to copy the remaining commits, giving:

```
             G'-H'  <-- HEAD
            /
...--F--I--J   <-- master, origin/master, upstream/master
      \
       G--H   <-- workbranch, origin/workbranch
```

Now that all commits are successfully copied (or you've fixed them up and used `git rebase --continue` as needed), Git yanks the name `workbranch` over to point to the `H'` commit, and re-attaches `HEAD`:

```
             G'-H'  <-- workbranch (HEAD)
            /
...--F--I--J   <-- master, origin/master, upstream/master
      \
       G--H   <-- origin/workbranch
```

It *seems* as though the two existing commits somehow moved, because the new commits have the same author and time-stamp and log message and so on.  What's different are the commit *numbers*, but who actually bothers to *look* at those big ugly hash IDs?

Our Git has deliberately *forgotten* that `workbranch` used to point to commit `H`.  Instead, our `workbranch` now points at new-and-improved commit `H'`.  Note, though, that our Git remembers that the Git over at `origin` has *their* `workbranch` remembering existing commit `H`.

#### `git push`

Suppose we now have our Git call up *their* Git, over at `origin`, and send commits `G'-H'` to them:

```
git push origin workbranch
```

They'll put `G'` and `H'` into their own repository, temporarily at least, and then consider our request to have them change *their* name `workbranch` to point to commit `H'`.  But now, they will say *no*.

When we ask them, politely, to move their `workbranch` from their (and our) `H` to our (and theirs now too) `H'`, they say *no* because if they did that, they would forget how to find commit `H`.  They have no idea that `H'` is a new-and-improved *replacement* for `H`.  They know only that if they do what we ask, they will *forget* `H`.  They won't have a name by which they can still find `H`.

So, they say no.

#### `git pull`

If you now run `git pull origin workbranch`, or even just `git pull` with no arguments, you now have your Git call up their Git and ask them about *their* `workbranch`.  They will say: *Oh, sure, my `workbranch`, it has these two perfectly good commits `G` and `H` on it, would you like them?*  If your Git has thrown out your old `G-H` already, it takes these copies.  If not—and your Git is certain to still have them, because your `origin/workbranch` keeps remembering them—your Git says it already has them, but thanks anyway, and now your Git knows that their `workbranch` points to commit `H`.  So your Git updates your `origin/workbranch`, if needed (it isn't, as your `origin/workbranch` already still remembers `H`):

```
             G'-H'  <-- workbranch (HEAD)
            /
...--F--I--J   <-- master, origin/master, upstream/master
      \
       G--H   <-- origin/workbranch
```

and *now* **your** Git runs the second half of any `git pull`.

The `git pull` command really consists of running *two* Git commands:

- The first command is always `git fetch`.  That's the step that has your Git call up their Git and ask them about their `workbranch` (and maybe their other branches too, depending on how you run `git fetch`).  This step brings over any commits they have, that you don't, that your Git will need.  Then your Git updates your `origin/*` names wherever that's necessary.
- The second command defaults to `git merge`.  The merge runs on whatever commit they said is *their* branch's last commit.

So here, your Git runs `git merge` on the hash ID of commit `H`—their `workbranch`, which is your `origin/workbranch`.  So your Git now *merges* your commit `H'` with the shared commit `H`:

```
             G'-H'-M  <-- workbranch (HEAD)
            /     /
...--F--I--J  <- / -- master, origin/master, upstream/master
      \         /
       G-------H   <-- origin/workbranch
```

Those copies you made, to improve and discard the old `G-H`, are still there.  The old `G-H` are still there too.  New merge commit `M` brings *both branches* together.  The fact that one branch consists of commits you thought you'd gotten rid of isn't important.  The commits still exist, and the merge merges them.

#### `git push`, again

Your Git can now send their Git commit `M`, the new merge.  If they make their `workbranch` identify commit `M`, their existing commits `G-H` remain accessible in *their* repository, so they are satisfied with that.  But at this point, you have duplicates of all the commits your `git rebase` copied (and now they will too).  This isn't what you wanted at all.

Note: a successful `git push` will update your `origin/workbranch` to remember the fact that their `workbranch` now remembers commit `M`, so now the drawing looks like this:

```
             G'-H'-M  <-- workbranch (HEAD), origin/workbranch
            /     /
...--F--I--J  <- / -- master, origin/master, upstream/master
      \         /
       G-------H
```

(We could probably simplify this by moving the `G-H` line to the top of the drawing, but let's not do that.)

To fix the problem, you must do the following:

- Force your Git to pretend you never made merge commit `M` at all.
- Force the Git over at `origin` to set *his* `workbranch` name to remember commit `H'` instead of `M`.

The easiest set of Git commands to do this at this point are `git reset --hard` and `git push --force`.  Let's see how those work.

#### `git reset --hard`

We'll start by making *our* Git forget our commit `M`:

```
git checkout workbranch         # if needed - we're probably already there
```

This ensures that we have:

```
             G'-H'-M  <-- workbranch (HEAD), origin/workbranch
            /     /
...--F--I--J  <- / -- master, origin/master, upstream/master
      \         /
       G-------H
```

in our repository now.  Then:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

The `HEAD~1` notation means *move back one first-parent*, from commit `M` to commit `H'`.  That makes our name `workbranch` point to commit `H'`.  To draw this, let's move commit `M` down to the bottom row:

```
             G'-H'  <-- workbranch (HEAD)
            /    \
...--F--I--J   <- \ -- master, origin/master, upstream/master
      \            \
       G-------H----M   <-- origin/workbranch
```

Now that our `workbranch` identifies commit `H'`, we run:

```
git push --force origin workbranch
```

This has our Git call up their Git, over at `origin`, tell it about commit `H'`—they already have it of course, at this point—and then command them, forcefully: *Set your branch name `workbranch` to point to commit `H'`!*  (This is from `--force`, and takes the place of the usual polite request.)

Assuming they obey—that part is up to them, but if you have control over this repository, just make sure you give yourself force-push permissions—they will move *their* `workbranch` to point to commit `H'`, and your Git will update your `origin/workbranch` accordingly:

```
             G'-H'  <-- workbranch (HEAD), origin/workbranch
            /    \
...--F--I--J   <- \ -- master, origin/master, upstream/master
      \            \
       G-------H----M   [abandoned]
```

Now that they, and you, don't have a *name* by which to *find* commit `M`, you won't even see it.  All will be as if it never existed:

```
             G'-H'  <-- workbranch (HEAD), origin/workbranch
            /
...--F--I--J   <-- master, origin/master, upstream/master
```

#### Again, this is a normal thing with rebase

The issue with rebasing is that it works by *copying* commits to new-and-improved commits.

The issue with Git in general is that it is loath to give up commits.  It *wants* to *add* commits, not remove them in favor of new and improved commits.

Every Git repository will easily *add new commits*.  It won't so easily *forget* an old one.  So to send this particular commit to `origin`, when `origin` remembers your old commit `H` instead of your new-and-improved `H'`, you must force the push.  You can use `--force-with-lease`, which adds a kind of safety check, that their `workbranch` still remembers `H` and not some other commit.

If there are other users of the `origin` Git repository, remember that they, too, might be using or adding on to `origin`'s `workbranch`.  You should make sure that all of these users *expect* commits to be removed and replaced.  Otherwise those other users will be surprised by this kind of action.

Avoiding rebase entirely avoids this kind of surprise, but ultimately it is really up to you and anyone you work with.  If you all agree that rebases happen—that some commits can go away, and you won't bring them back if they're supposed to *stay* gone—then you can work this way.